# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a kubernetes cluster,I have Ubuntu on my VMS :

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
```

when I try to execute these cmds :

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

then this error occurs when I run

```
sudo apt update :
```

the error :

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

Could you help please to fix this issue ?